# A 32bit version of an application, built on CentOS 6 x64, crashes during exceptions in `dl_iterate_phdr`, when started on newer Linux

Tags: c++, linux, exception, glibc

**TL;DR;** My research shows that if I build an application (and its dependencies) on older Linux like `CentOS 6` (with `GLIBC 2.12`), it is supposed to work perfectly fine on any other Linux distro, which has newer `GLIBC`. Isn't this assumption correct?

---

Sorry, it's gonna be a long post, but it's not a trivial question.

Here's the **build** machine:

```
$ rpm -q centos-release
  centos-release-6-10.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64
$ ldd --version
  ldd (GNU libc) 2.12
$ ld -v
  GNU ld version 2.30-54.el6
$ gcc --version
  gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
$ g++ --version
  g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
```

The **application** links with almost everything statically, so:

```
$ ldd ./app 
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f73000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7f4c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf7f41000)
libstdc++.so.6 => ./libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7e22000)
libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7d53000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => ./libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7d35000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7d14000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7b36000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f75000)
```

So:

- `linux-gate` and `ld-linux` aren't exactly libs, so they can't be deployed;
- `libdl`, `librt`, `libm`, `libpthread` and `libc` are a part of the `GLIBC`, so they shouldn't be deployed as well (especially given the backward compatibility of the GNU C library);
- `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` are "deployed" together with the binary (taken from the build machine)

The **test** machine:

```
$ lsb_release -a
  Description:  Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
$ ldd --version
  ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) 2.28
```

The 64bit build (with its `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s`) seems to work perfectly fine.

The issue is with the 32bit build - it **crashes**, when an exception is thrown (not for all exceptions, but seems to be consistent). Here's how interesting the stack trace is:

```
 SIGSEGV at  0# __kernel_sigreturn in linux-gate.so.1
 1# dl_iterate_phdr in /lib32/libc.so.6
 2# _Unwind_Find_FDE in ./libgcc_s.so.1
 3# 0xF7D88AAE in ./libgcc_s.so.1
 4# 0xF7D89227 in ./libgcc_s.so.1
 5# _Unwind_RaiseException in ./libgcc_s.so.1
 6# __cxa_throw in ./libstdc++.so.6
 7# <some funct> in ./app
 7# <some funct> in ./app
 7# <some funct> in ./app
 7# <some funct> in ./app
 7# <some funct> in ./app
 7# <some funct> in ./app
13# make_fcontext in ./app
```

I can see two possible options here:

1. there's something broken with the 32bit build (although it works without exceptions);
2. I do have some big misunderstanding on the matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrectly optimistic. Porting to newer versions of libraries, toolsets and operating systems often involves some reading of docs about breaking changes and full retesting. Some undefined behavior in code just did manifest differently or less frequently and bang.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm not sure I understand what libraries/toolsets you're talking about? Everything used in `app` is built on the same build machine, with the same environment and (almost) everything is statically linked. Are you saying, that deploying `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` is wrong? Looking at the dependencies, the only question seems to be `GLIBC` which is supposed to be fully backward compatible. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I did read that you compare 32 bit and for 64 bit builds. Expected behavior of program is different since sizes of pointers and integral types in it are different, the instructions in resulting executables are different, tools generating those executables are different, libraries linked to are different and so on.

Comment: What's your link command? Why didn't you statically link to *g++*'s libs? Also, can you reproduce the problem with a dummy *main* only containing a `std::cout`?

Comment: @CristiFati what's the point of static linking with g++ and gcc libs in this case? I do "deploy" and link with them anyway. I didn't do that, because static linking with these 2 libs has some risks, which I'd like to avoid (e.g. runtime `dlopen`). About the dummy `main` (with exceptions, though) - that's fair point, I'll try that. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: I suspect that if you "deploy" GCC libs (g++/gcc) from build machine to target one with different OS or version, then your app (or one of its dependencies) can actually use GCC libs from the target system, and other dependencies use libs that you deployed, leading to incompatibilities. It's much safer to build applications on target box or use cross-compilation specifying exactly target box OS and version. Also it's safer to use dynamic linking with system libs because mixing static and dynamic lib in one app may lead to problems (e.g. two instances of some global var in gcc lib).

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat I do use dynamic linking with the system libs. Also, see the dependencies of the application - every dep is statically linked into the executable and each of these deps are built against the deployed c++/gcc libs - so I can't see how it's possible to mix two implementations of these libs into the binary. Is it possible? And what I'm trying to do is to build an app on older Linux (in this case - CentOS 6) in order to support wider Linux distros (with older GLIBC), so building for a specific hardware/platform is not an option.

Comment: @CristiFati can't reproduce it with a simple `main` and a simple `throw`. The real app is a bit big and has multiple dependencies. Maybe I've done something wrong when compiling them, but I can't think of a way to find that out.

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash with minimal example from https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr ? Does your program actually use dl_iterate_phdr()?

Comment: @KirilKirov I mentioned dynamic linking mainly as a reaction to CristiFati's question/suggestion. I copied my comment to a separate answer.

Comment: What about if you add smh like `pthread_self();` (`#include <pthread.h>` required)?

Comment: @CristiFati - nope, works fine

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you "deploy" GCC libs (g++/gcc) from build machine to target one with different OS or OS version, then your app (or one of its dependencies) can actually use GCC libs from the target system, and other dependencies use libs that you deployed, leading to potential incompatibilities.

It's much safer to build your application on target box, or use cross-compilation specifying exactly target box OS and version.

Also it's safer to use dynamic linking with system libs because otherwise you may end up with the situation of mixing static and dynamic lib in one app, and this may lead to problems (e.g. two instances of some global var in gcc lib).

You'll need to check whole tree of lib dependencies to ensure that only one instance of every lib is loaded from the same location. For example your app depends on `./libgcc_s.so.1` and `./libstdc++.so.6` but `./libstdc++.so.6` may depend on system's `libgcc_s.so`.

You may search on Internet about these and other pitfalls with building your app on non-target box. E.g. [here](https://github.com/phusion/holy-build-box#problem-introduction):

> So just compiling your application on an older distribution is not enough.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link to `phusion/holy-build-box`, I haven't seen this, will definitely take a look! As I already said, I can't see how the application can look for the local (target machine's) c++/gcc, as `ldd` clearly shows a different thing. I also mentioned in the comments above, that I do link with the system libs dynamically (e.g.`libc`, `libm`, ...; c++/gcc libs are not "system" libs). I don't say you're wrong, I'm just trying to explain what I think and trying to find out where's/re my mistake/s.

Comment: Oh, this `holy build box` is just some docker container. Also, they seem to explain exactly what I've already done: `The solution is to statically link to dependencies. ... the Holy Build Box approach is to statically link to all dependencies, except for glibc and other system libraries that are found on pretty much every Linux distribution, such as libpthread and libm.`. My build machine is also `CentOS 6`, I'm also not linking with glibc statically, but everything else is statically linked, etc. Of course, I need to read that more carefully, but seems like I'm doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: @KirilKirov May your crash be related to 32/64-bit lib versions incompatibilty in some linked libs? What does `ldd ./libstdc++.so.6` show, for example? Check whole dependency tree, not just app's.

Comment: @KirilKirov Also read this: https://github.com/phusion/holy-build-box/blob/master/LINKING-CXX.md

Comment: `ldd ./libstdc++.so.6 
 linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7fce000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7df3000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7c15000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7fd0000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => ./libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7bf7000)
`

Comment: `ldd ./libgcc_s.so.1 
 linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f00000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7ce3000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f02000)`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. Everything seems right. I also though `ldd` is recursive, isn't it? I'll inspect all `dlopen` calls with `strace`, but I doubt this is an issue, given the fact I override `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it has top priority when searching for libs.

Comment: @KirilKirov Last two `ldd`s look fine to me.